# Publishing website created using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, deployment, crystal-reports

I have created a website with asp.net and uses oracle connectivity with pl/sql developer.i have uses the crystal report which is a third party tool. how to purchase it.
i am using visual studio 2005 and yes i am using basic crystal crystal that comes with visual studio.
Now suppose i hav purchase a domain www.abc.com. 
and i want to pubsite it. i have uses the crystal report which is a third party tool. how to purchase it.
plz give a expert advice.
Thankyou.

Comment: Some information here would be useful: what version of Visual Studio have you used to build the website? Are you using the basic Crystal Reports that comes with Visual Studio?

Comment: i am using visual studio 2005 and yes i am using basic crystal crystal that comes with visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally when you publish a website that makes use of Crystal Reports, the necessary DLLs are/must be included in the package you deploy on your webserver.

Read these pages for more details:

[Deployment Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225245%28VS.90%29.aspx)

[Features of Crystal Reports for Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225360%28VS.90%29.aspx)

[How to deploy the Crystal Reports 2008 Basic Runtime](http://weblogs.asp.net/guybarrette/archive/2008/04/24/how-to-deploy-the-crystal-reports-2008-basic-runtime.aspx)

Comment: i hav check your link.where would i add i will add my database part

Comment: Basically you must have a database server (can be the same server where you deploy the website). Oracle must be installed on the server. You then create the database on the server and change your website connection string used to connect to the database so that it points to Oracle on the webserver instead of the local Oracle instance you used to develop the website.

Comment: i have oracle 10g intall on my computer and it uses database part after checking connection string and suppose need first my project,crystal report(licence may be) thirdly my oracle database would would require to run the entire software.
Lets example I hav purchased a webspace say www.abc.com now all the things bust be deploy to server to run it. thats what i am asking.?

Comment: When you buy a web address (www.abc.com) in your situation you must have a hosting plan (http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/virtual-dedicated-servers.aspx?ci=9013) that gives you database support (in your case Oracle). If you used the basic Crystal Reports you won't need a license at all.

Comment: ok.i have not yet purchase bt i will see.thanks i am accepting ur answer